# How to use UserDefaults to keep track of which posts a user has voted on?

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to keep track of which posts a user has voted on to avoid users being able to close the app and revote on a post that they have already voted on.

Here is where I initialize and load my `userDefaults`:

```
let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard

override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()
   tableView.reloadData()
   self.reloadInputViews()
   tableView.dataSource = self
   tableView.register(UINib(nibName: K.cellNibName, bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: K.cellIdentifier)
   if let leftPostArray = userDefaults.array(forKey: leftKey) as? [String]{
      votedLeftPosts = leftPostArray
   }
   if let rightPostArray = userDefaults.array(forKey: rightKey) as? [String]{
      votedRightPosts = rightPostArray
   }
}
```

And then where I update `userDefaults`:

```
//Run when user presses the button on the left in a post
    func userVotedLeft(_ postCell: PostCell) {
        print(votedLeftPosts)
        guard let indexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: postCell) else { return }
        let post = posts[indexPath.row]
        if(votedLeftPosts.contains(post.firstImageUrl)){
            return
        }else if(votedRightPosts.contains(post.firstImageUrl)){
            increment(fbLeftKey, post)
            decrement(fbRightKey, post)
            votedRightPosts.remove(at: votedRightPosts.firstIndex(of: post.firstImageUrl)!)
        }else{
            increment(fbLeftKey, post)
        }
        votedLeftPosts.append(post.firstImageUrl)
        userDefaults.set(votedLeftPosts, forKey: fbLeftKey)
        userDefaults.set(votedRightPosts, forKey: fbRightKey)
    }
    
    //Run when the user presses the button on the right in a post
    func userVotedRight(_ postCell: PostCell) {
        print((userDefaults.array(forKey: fbRightKey) ?? []) as [String])
        guard let indexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: postCell) else { return }
        let post = posts[indexPath.row]
        if(votedRightPosts.contains(post.firstImageUrl)){
            return
        }else if(votedLeftPosts.contains(post.firstImageUrl)){
            increment(fbRightKey, post)
            decrement(fbLeftKey, post)
            votedLeftPosts.remove(at: votedLeftPosts.firstIndex(of: post.firstImageUrl)!)

        }else{
            increment(fbLeftKey, post)
        }
        votedRightPosts.append(post.firstImageUrl)
        userDefaults.set(votedLeftPosts, forKey: fbLeftKey)
        userDefaults.set(votedRightPosts, forKey: fbRightKey)
    }
```

Right now I am still able to vote on a post, then restart the app and vote on the same post.

Comment: What do the methods `increment` and `decrement` do?

Comment: Also, does the `firstImageUrl` property uniquely identify a post? I.e., does it remain the same across multiple app launches? I see that you're printing your arrays in the beginning of `userVotedLeft` and `userVotedRight ` methods, does the output contain the URL of the post when you're trying to vote for it again?

Comment: @VadimBelyaev `increment` and `decrement` access firebase and increase and decrease the vote respectively. `firstImageUrl` is unique across multiple launches as it is a URL retrieved from firestore. I was printing those arrays in order to see if they were written to as those methods were called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're reading from UserDefaults using the keys `leftKey` and `rightKey`, and then saving to `UserDefaults` using the keys `fbLeftKey` and `fbRightKey`. If those variables contain different strings then the values you save won't be loaded.

If they contain the same strings, why are there different variable names? That's a bug waiting to happen.

You should also be aware that if you kill your app in the debugger, it likely won't save `UserDefaults` changes to "disk." You have to press the home button to switch your app to the background in order to get your `UserDefaults` changes to be saved.

Comment: So was the problem mis-matched keys between saving and loading your settings?